# Block flatness tolerance?

Tags: engine, overheating, block, ecotec, tolerance

2006 Solstice (says hello). The engine overheated for some reason, going from ~200F to ~300F in a matter of seconds. (Actually, the gauge changed *directly* from 203F to 298F.) The head is over at the machine shop getting milled and a valve job. They said it was "pretty warped," but didn't say how much and it didn't occur to me to ask.

Now, obviously I need to check the block, as well, and I don't really want to pull the engine if it's not necessary.

This is a 2010 GM LE5 (Ecotec 2.4L) from a Malibu, aluminum block and head.

When checking with the straight edge and feeler gauge, how much variance is acceptable?

Comment: Observing your questions on that solstice: I admire your patience

Comment: @Myself Thank you. It's been an adventure. But, I've learned a LOT.

Comment: related- https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1917/22368

Comment: I'm seeing .004" on an aluminum block, but not specifically for the LE5. That's corner to corner. Also, when I see a temperature change like that, it usually indicates a steam pocket has encountered the temperature sender.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks. If not for an LE5, is it for an I4? Also, I found a leak at the upper radiator hose. 9PSI with the pressure pump pushed coolant out, cap says it should support 15 PSI. My working theory is that coolant got pushed out, got too low in the head and block, overheated and warped, and the head gasket just gave up. :/

Comment: That sounds very promising as the culprit. The spec I gave is actually for an LS1 deck, but with four cylinders across and an aluminum block, it should be about the same. I'm not seeing anything handy for an aluminum I4, but I didn't look *too hard*, either.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, removed my answer - which actually led to more detail than you have offered. But, as you say it's only a comment.

Comment: @SolarMike - Having talked with David before, he knows how to do the measurement. He just needs to know the tolerance. My suggestion to him is an educated guess based on a few things, but I'm not trying to give him an answer ... which is why it's a comment.

Comment: So, what is the tolerance in terms of width and length ? corner to corner is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Longitudinal .002", Transverse .0012", Overall .004",
Minimum deck height from the top of the main bearing journal to the deck is 7.4511"
It's an interference motor...if modifications have been made to the valve train, pay close attention to your installed valve height of 1.2795. A decked block and a  shaved head that was "pretty warped", with a stock head gasket could equal valve to piston contact in an interference motor, make sure you check...especially if reliefs are already cut into the piston.

Comment: Thanks! It's been reassembled and running for awhile, but this is valuable information. Adding it to the notes section in my service manual. Where did you find this? If it's in the FSM, I haven't found it.